# Porting concurrent java classes to c#

Tags: c#, java

I'am trying to port high_scale_lib by Cliff Click
http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/
to c# but there is some java classes i can't find c# equivalent for it like

```
AtomicLongFieldUpdater
```

and what is the sun.misc.Unsafe type in java is it the same as pointer in c# or IntPtr ?
and my last question are all java objects are nullable ?

Comment: `sun.misc.Unsafe` is not a pointer, and yes, all non-primitive Java values can be set to `null`.

Comment: Just to be clear: anything using `sun.misc.Unsafe` is not portable Java, so it's certain to be doing other things that will make your port not go smoothly. Much better would be to just read the existing code for ideas and write a new implementation in idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having read the code, I even more strongly advise not to try to port it directly. The code as written does insane things with Java internals in an attempt to squeeze out razor thin margins of performance. The equivalent C# code might not perform as well, or different techniques might be needed to achieve the same results.

Basically: if you don't already understand exactly what that Java code is doing and why it is doing it that way (and I don't claim to understand it myself) then you're probably not qualified to attempt to port it to a different language on a different platform with a different memory model and different concurrency guarantees.